# Как выбрать случайное слово из предложенных c#

Tags: c#

Как в c# с помощью Random выбрать случайное слово типа:
string name = Random.что_то("Tom", "Jack", "John");
Есть такой метод, который может это сделать без надобности создания массива?

Comment: `string name = new string[] { "Tom", "Jack", "John" }[Random.Shared.Next(3)];`

Comment: @aepot: Ого, круто, не знал про `Random.Shared`.

Comment: @VladD оно в .NET Core появилось. Как раз тогда, когда болезнь нулевого сида вылечили. Собственно он и генерит сиды для новых рандомов, создаваемых через дефолтный конструктор.

Comment: @aepot: А, это и есть начальный seed?

Comment: @VladD шаред заряжается от даты вроде или винапи, а остальные от шареда. Надо в исходники смотреть, давно я их видел, могу что-то напутать. Там насколько имплементаций намешано.

Comment: @aepot: Я видел в исходниках, что использовался один экземпляр для создания сидов, но с .NET 6 они поменяли алгоритм, и теперь каждый `new Random()` (_без_ сида) создаёт экземпляр некоего `Xoshiro256**`.  А раньше (а также сейчас для производных классов) таки [используется `Shared.Next()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Random.Net5CompatImpl.cs,104) в качестве сида.

Comment: При этом сам `Shared.Next()` использует Xoshiro, а не таймер, под капотом. А Xoshiro для сида берёт 4 ulong, которые [генерируются из arc4random_buf](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7414af2a5f6d8d99efc27d3f5ef7a394e0b23c42/src/native/libs/System.Native/pal_random.c#L26). (Это только под Unix, что ли?)